# Could a complicated premium role function in Firebase Security Rules affect performance?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am working on the following function to centralize and avoid code duplication, in order to prevent clutter in the rules file. However, I have some concerns regarding the performance of this function and whether this implementation could be considered an anti-pattern. I'm also unsure about the methods used and whether they are supported by the Firebase rules engine, regarding why there is many roles its due to the fact that each one will later on represent a tier.

below is my function code :

```js
function isPremium(requestData) {
  // trial expiry calclation
  let currentTime = requestData.time.toMillis();
  let threeDaysAgo = currentTime - (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  let createdAt = requestData.auth.token.createdAt.toMillis();
  // Role
  let stripeRole = requestData.auth.token.stripeRole;
  // available primium for all users. 
  let premiumUserRoles = ['premium-user', 'premium-user-50', 'premium-user-100'];
  let premiumSuperUserRoles = ['premium-super-user', 'premium-super-user-50', 'premium-super-user-100'];
 
  let allPremiumRoles = premiumUserRoles.concat(premiumSuperUserRoles);

  return (
    premiumRoles.includes(stripeRole) ||
    (stripeRole === 'trial' && createdAt >= threeDaysAgo)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no known performance problems with security rules for any allowed complexity.  They are intentionally [limited in capability](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits) precisely for this reason.